# How can I make this tile map correctly?

Tags: opengl, mathematics, c

I'm having the following problem creating this hexa tiled map.

this is what I wanted :

[image: desired output]

[EDIT]
Ok I've Managed to do this:

```
const float scaleX = ((float)tileWidth) / 10000,
    scaleY = ((float)tileHeight ) / 10000;
    const float hexagon_r = scaleY / 2;
    const float hexagon_dx = hexagon_r * cosf(30*3.14f / 180.0);
    const float hexagon_dy = hexagon_r * sinf(30*3.14f / 180.0);
    const float hexagon_gx = 2.0*hexagon_dx;
    const float hexagon_gy = 2.0*hexagon_dx*sinf(60*3.14f / 180.0);
    Vector2 auxPos;
    auxPos.x = 0;
    auxPos.y = 0;
    float j = 0;
    for (unsigned int y = 0; y < layer->layerHeight; y++, j += hexagon_gx * 2)
    {
        auxPos.y = y * (hexagon_gy * -2 );
        auxPos.x = j;
        for (unsigned int x = 0; x < layer->layerWidth; x++)
        {

            auxPos.x += hexagon_gx * 2;

            float angle =90 * 3.14f / 180;

            auxPos.y += hexagon_gy * 2;

            SetData(stack->vData, stack->vCounter + 0, auxPos.x + ((-scaleX) * cosf(angle) + (-scaleY) * -sinf(angle)));
            SetData(stack->vData, stack->vCounter + 1, auxPos.y + ((-scaleX) * sinf(angle) + (-scaleY) * cosf(angle)));
            SetData(stack->vData, stack->vCounter + 2, layer->layerDepth);

            SetData(stack->vData, stack->vCounter + 3, auxPos.x + ((scaleX) * cosf(angle) + (-scaleY) * -sinf(angle)));
            SetData(stack->vData, stack->vCounter + 4, auxPos.y + ((scaleX) * sinf(angle) + (-scaleY) * cosf(angle)));
            SetData(stack->vData, stack->vCounter + 5, layer->layerDepth);

            SetData(stack->vData, stack->vCounter + 6, auxPos.x + ((scaleX) * cosf(angle) + (scaleY) * -sinf(angle)));
            SetData(stack->vData, stack->vCounter + 7, auxPos.y + ((scaleX) * sinf(angle) + (scaleY) * cosf(angle)));
            SetData(stack->vData, stack->vCounter + 8, layer->layerDepth);

            SetData(stack->vData, stack->vCounter + 9, auxPos.x + ((-scaleX) * cosf(angle) + (scaleY) * -sinf(angle)));
            SetData(stack->vData, stack->vCounter + 10, auxPos.y + ((-scaleX) * sinf(angle) + (scaleY) * cosf(angle)));
            SetData(stack->vData, stack->vCounter + 11, layer->layerDepth);
        }
    }
```

[image: output]

can't seem to make this work...

Comment: please help me!!

Comment: I think you would have more luck using (1/3)$pi$ (60 degrees) instead of (1/2)$pi$ (90 degrees).

Comment: come on... that doesn't help anything.... what do you mean?

Comment: What happens when you use 'angle = 60 * 3.14f / 180;' ... It looks like your tiles are getting stretched because of this

Comment: the tiles get rotated 60 degrees. the gap continues.. I've tred auxPos.y += scaleY * 2; Which makes the tiles evenly spaced out but there's still gaps in between I'l edit the question...

Comment: the streching is not important... the problem is how i spce them correctly

Comment: I highly recommend reading this tutorial for implementing hexagonal maps: https://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/